# I am trying to combine or aggregate 2 rows of data into 1 row by a certain criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, tidyr

I am attempting to combine 2 rows into 1 row and select the value to keep depending on a different column.

```
ID  score  date     std error
123 87    1/15/2018    5
123 92    1/15/2018    10
155 78    3/10/2018    8
155 82    1/15/2018    7
```

In the data set I only want 1 row per ID. When there are two different test scores I want to keep the score value with the corresponding test date that is closest to present day. If the date is the same then I want to take the test score with the smallest standard error.

End result would look like this:

```
ID  score   test date   std error
123 87      1/15/2018   5
155 78     3/10/2018    8
```

Being going at it few a few hours and cannot seem to figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: welcome to SO, nice first question. What if both date and SD are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrange` by *date* (descending order) and *std error* (ascending order) then take the first row from each group:

```
df %>% 
    arrange(desc(as.Date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')), std.error) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% slice(1)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID score date      std.error
#  <int> <int> <fct>         <int>
#1   123    87 1/15/2018         5
#2   155    78 3/10/2018         8
```

Comment: @Jake when you are happy with an answer, accept it: tick the check mark below the answer you want to accept